# Cannot work with scala sbt behind corporate firewall

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am a newbie for scala, trying to work with play framework. After creating a simple scala play app using activator (1.3.6), I am trying to run it. I have tried both activator and sbt (0.13.9, downloaded separately).
For activator, I get this error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\admr229\my-second-app\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/admr229/my-second-app/project/}my-second-app-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.c
om/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.
org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org
/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.4.4/sbt-plugin-2.4.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\admr229\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.4.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\admr229\my-second-app\repository\com.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.4.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\typesafe-activator-1.3.6\activator-dist-1.3.6\repository\com.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.4.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.4.4/sbt-plugin-2.4.4.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.4.4/sbt-plugin-2.4.4.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.4 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.4 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\admr229\my-second-app\project\plugins.sbt#L2-3)
[warn]            +- default:my-second-app-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

If I try with sbt run, instead of activator run, result is little different (instead of certification error, its connection timeout):

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\admr229\my-second-app\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/admr229/my-second-app/project/}my-second-app-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
[warn] ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.4.4/sbt-plugin-2.4.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.4 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.4 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\admr229\my-second-app\project\plugins.sbt#L2-3)
[warn]            +- default:my-second-app-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.4: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Now, my environment is windows, and sbt is installed (extracted zipped contents) at: C:\sbt-0.13.9
It seems, sbt is trying to resolve a non-existing resource! I tried to visit the url (https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml). So, I created repositories file in 'C:\sbt-0.13.9.sbt', hoping that it will override the existing repositories. Nothing changed. Content of the repositories file:

```
[repositories]
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo1.maven.org/
```

I tried with non https paths, because I do not know what my proxy server settings are for https (if that is different). But, I know the http details and updated sbtconfig.txt accordingly (with the same proxy settings, my other projects with maven work else where):

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.corporate.proxyadd -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxySet=true 
-Dsbt.repository.config=C:\sbt-0.13.9\.sbt\repositories
```

Nothing works. Always the same error. Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does maven work? I assume your firewall does MITM https?

Comment: Yes, maven works for my java projects. But, I am not sure about 'MITM' bit, no clue what that means. All I can say, they have this dynamic proxy settings file (proxy.pac) where they have code to define the proxy address. But, yea, I don't use https for maven either.

Comment: I have to install our corporate cert to my java installation. Googling the error message works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: @som-snytt Where do I get my corporate certificate? Or should I be using typesafe's certificate in this case? I tried with typesafe's certificate from the link. Though the full link is not accessible, it can be accessible upto ../sbt_0.13/ and I tried with that. Unfortunately, no result.